# EnableCors not working in WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, cors

I followed the [aspnet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) site tutorial to enable cors and i cant get it working.

Register method on WebApiConfig:

```
  public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
  {
        config.EnableCors(new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*"));
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
   }
```

Controller:

```
 public class TestController : Controller
 {
    [Route("test/{*anything}")]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return Json(new { test = "test message" },
            JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
  }
```

Then i create a simple website with a minimum index.html served by the nodejs live-server making an ajax request and it works ok when debuggin locally. But when i publish it to azure i get the following error :

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://mysite.azurewebsites.net . No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access

**EDIT:**
I have installed the  `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Cors` version `5.2.3`

Comment: Is this your api controller or mvc controller? Unless you are using DotNet Core, the base class should be ApiController

Comment: Maybe related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35432709/application-using-cors-does-not-work-in-azure

Comment: It is an mvc controller, i see now, but the project is a webapi project.

Comment: Change it to ApiController with action return type I`HttpResponseMessage` and return `Ok (new { test = "test message" });`

Comment: @Developer Worked!

Comment: Can you also include request/response headers you are getting locally and on Azure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you are using MVC Controller instead of Api Controller (unless its DotNet Core). Change the Base class to `ApiController` with action return type `IHttpResponseMessage` and `return Ok (new { test = "test message" });`